# Access attribute of parents context in Meteor Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

In my scenario, I'm using "with" to switch the context to a related object, I'm getting from my helper, based on the ID of the parent.

```
Template.my_template.helpers({
   my_related_object: function(){
      return MyRelatedObjectsCollection.findOne({parentId:this_id});
   }
});


<template name="my_template">
<h1>{{name}}</h1>

{{#with my_related_object}}
   <span>{{name}} is related to {{here I want to display the parents name}}</span>    
{{/with}}   
</template>
```

How can I access the attributes of my parent object within the "with" context?

Comment: it looks like the template, as is, will quickly walk up the parent chain, because my_related_object keeps getting replaced as its id is updated. what you really want is access to the original object and its parent at the same time, yes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use directory style directory navigation in blaze templates to access ancestor data contexts. In your case:

```
<template name="my_template">
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
{{#with my_related_object}}
   <span>{{../name}} is the name of the parent object</span>    
{{/with}}   
</template>
```